# sqlite3 select records from multiple tables

Tags: sqlite, node-sqlite3

I am a little stuck on a fairly simple sqlite query - perhaps because I've been looking at the issue for several hours and need a break.

I have 2 tables (lets assume transactions only deals with incoming funds for now):

```
            db.run(`CREATE TABLE accounts (
                sort TEXT NOT NULL,
                account TEXT NOT NULL,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                balance REAL DEFAULT 0.00,
                PRIMARY KEY(routing, account)
            );`);
            db.run(`CREATE TABLE transactions (
                id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                to_sort TEXT NOT NULL,
                to_account TEXT NOT NULL,
                amount REAL NOT NULL,
                currency TEXT DEFAULT "USD"
            );`);
```

and just for this example, lets say I have the following in my accounts table:

```
sort: 123 account: 123456
sort: 456 account: 456789
sort: 789 account: 789100
```

I am able to select transactions for individual accounts fairly easily.
I just do a "select * from transactions where to_sort = '123' and to_account='123456'"

The transactions table count potentially have lots of transactions, some of which are valid and related to the above accounts. Some of which may be from random accounts (i.e. sort: 999, account: 99999)

My question is pertaining to the following scenarios:
I want to be able to select all transactions that are related to all accounts in the accounts table. For example I want every every transaction for the above 3 accounts only.

I think this would be along the lines of:

```
SELECT * from transactions, accounts 
WHERE transactions.to_sort = accounts.sort 
AND transactions.to_account = accounts.account
ORDER BY
    transactions.to_sort ASC, transactions.to_account ASC
```

I want to be able to select all transaction that are NOT related to the accounts in the accounts table. I'm a little confused by this as the primary key in the accounts table is a composite key. For a single column key, I could do a "...where id not in (select id from accounts)". But I'm not quite sure what to do with the tables above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE NOT transactions.to_sort = accounts.sort
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to select all transaction that are NOT related to
> the accounts in the accounts table

The easiest way to do this is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM accounts a 
  WHERE a.account = t.to_account AND a.sort = t.to_sort
)
```